# Iceberg: LGit_GIT_ERROR: Invalid version 0 on git_remote_callback

Tags: git, smalltalk, pharo

I'm getting this error when trying to load my project into a fresh [Pharo](https://pharo.org) image using [Iceberg](https://github.com/pharo-vcs/iceberg):

```
LGit_GIT_ERROR: Invalid version 0 on git_remote_callback
```

Before loading my project I checked "Enable Metacelo Integration" and "Use custom SSH keys" in *System > Settings > Tools > Software Configuration Management > Icegerg*. Then I tried running the following Metacello script but it raised an error

```
Metacello new
    baseline: 'DataFrame';
    repository: 'github://PolyMathOrg/DataFrame';
    load.
```

Can someone tell me what this error message means and how to deal with it?

- **Image:** Pharo 6.1 64-bit (https://pharo.org/download)
- **OS:** MacOS High Sierra v.10.13.1

Comment: Update: I don't get this error if I don't _Enable Metacello Integration_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by updating Iceberg according to the [instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/pharo-vcs/iceberg#update-iceberg):

```
MetacelloPharoPlatform select.
#(
    'BaselineOfTonel'
    'BaselineOfLibGit'
    'BaselineOfIceberg'
    'Iceberg-UI' 
    'Iceberg-Plugin-GitHub' 
    'Iceberg-Plugin' 
    'Iceberg-Metacello-Integration' 
    'Iceberg-Libgit-Tonel' 
    'Iceberg-Libgit-Filetree' 
    'Iceberg-Libgit' 
    'Iceberg' 
    'LibGit-Core'
    'MonticelloTonel-Tests'
    'MonticelloTonel-Core'
    'MonticelloTonel-FileSystem' ) 
do: [ :each | (each asPackageIfAbsent: [ nil ]) ifNotNil: #removeFromSystem ].
Metacello new
    baseline: 'Iceberg';
    repository: 'github://pharo-vcs/iceberg:v0.6.5';
    load.
```